# Two large pipes in basement. What are they?

Tags: basement, pipe

I just purchased a home and have yet to move in. I am wondering what these large pipes in the basement might be? They both run to the area where the water heater and boiler are and then go up through the basement roof. Can anyone give some insight?

Thanks[image]

Comment: we need some more detail. For example, they are likely fuel exhaust pipes from the water heaters. However, if you have electric hot water heaters than this is probably not the case.

Comment: They look like exhaust pipes, maybe one for Radon?

Comment: A picture of what they are connected to would be far more useful than this picture. Could be intake and exhaust for a condensing boiler. Could be radon. Could be exhaust and exhaust for a condensing boiler and condensing water heater with intakes elsewhere. Could be waste and vent plumbing...

Comment: Looks like pipe for combustion air and exhaust to me probably for the furnace, water heater etc.

Comment: @EdBeal is PVC allowed (by code) for combustion exhaust?

Comment: I know several installs that it was according to the MFG directions and the coaxial vent through the roof was also PVC.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It is for the modern super-high-efficiency furnaces. Exhaust air comes out around 40°C or even lower.

Comment: sorry, i know this is an old post. But it still bothers me. I live in a townhouse community where all the houses are built the same. Mine is the only one that has these pipes going to the furnace in the basement. Why would the other furnaces not need it?